# Black background on ScrollView Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

[image]

How its find issue? I'm using the only fragment for showing map view

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                              xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                              android:id="@+id/map"
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="250dp"
                              map:mapType="normal"/>
```

Comment: did you try to use on actual device? i think this is a emulator issue

Comment: No, I m check mobile also, actually, the black background on scroll view showing problem in my mobile,& I'm trying to this code also.

Comment: while adding back ground transparent image and view map. showing good on some phone, in Samsung latest series mobile their issue showing continues.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use the `android:drawingCacheQuality` of scroll view and `android:alwaysDrawnWithCache`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   android:background="android:background="@android:color/white"
```

for scrollView attribute and if needed for fragment in xml file.